# Retrieving a value from passed argument

Tags: c, arguments, return

There must be something I'm misunderstanding, why does this not return 10?

```
int main() {

    float i = 0;
    func(i);
    printf("%f", i);

    return 0;
}


void func(float i) {

    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

         i += 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primitive types (like floats) are "passed by value", func() is really modifying a copy of i.

Comment: So in order to modify the original float do I need to reference it with a pointer?

Comment: In Cm your options are func takes a float* and works directly on it's contants. OR func() returns i when it is done OR func works on a flobal variable rather than a param (that is the worst of the 3 options ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is passed by value. Whatever changes you are making in your function are done to the copy of the passed value but not the actual one.
To make it modify the value of the original variable you should use a pointer to it, and pass the value of that pointer to your `func`.

Make your function like below:

```
void func(float *i) {
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

         *i += 2;
    }
}
```

And call this function as :

```
func(&i);
```